# how to get the new generated file name by codigniter in case if the file already exists

Tags: php, codeigniter

***how to get the new    generated file name by codigniter  in case if the file already exists?***

i am inserting image file into my project `(uploads)` folder  and its name `i.e image.png` into my database table.

say `car.png` is the image which exists in my `uploads` folder. if again i am trying to upload the `car.png` image, then currently it is saving like `car1.png` into my uploads folder without replacing the older image. i want to get the new image name i.e. `car1.png` to save into my db but it actually saving the name which i am sending from my form i.e `car.png`.

To get the file name i used

```
 $img1=$_FILES['img1']['name'];  
 //this gives me the name of file which i am uploading from my form  i.e car.png
```

Please help me to solve my problem. Please....

Comment: are you using the file upload class from codeigniter?

Comment: @FabioAntunes Obliviously i am using file upload class

Comment: The why do you use the native php variable $_FILES

Comment: @FabioAntunes That i used in my controller class  to get the file name i.e car.png to save into my db. - I am new in Codeigniter.-

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're not using file upload class from codeingiter. I advise you to use it because it will solve your problem.

If you a upload a file with the same name and in the options you passed you set overwrite to FALSE, codeigniter will rename your **car.png** to **car1.png** (or the next number that's available).

Then if upload was successful it will return an array with all the data related to that file

```
Array
(
    [file_name]    => mypic.jpg
    [file_type]    => image/jpeg
    [file_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/
    [full_path]    => /path/to/your/upload/jpg.jpg
    [raw_name]     => mypic
    [orig_name]    => mypic.jpg
    [client_name]  => mypic.jpg
    [file_ext]     => .jpg
    [file_size]    => 22.2
    [is_image]     => 1
    [image_width]  => 800
    [image_height] => 600
    [image_type]   => jpeg
    [image_size_str] => width="800" height="200"
)
```

As you can see, this way you will get the name of the file even if it changed.

You can read more about File Upload Class and how to implement it here:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

**EDIT2**
YOu have to name your input files on your view userfile1, userfile2, userfile3 and so on

```
class Upload extends CI_Controller {

  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
  }

  function index()
  {
    $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
  }

  function do_upload(){
   $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
   $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
   $config['max_size']    = '100';
   $config['max_width']  = '1024';
   $config['max_height']  = '768';

   $this->load->library('upload', $config);
   foreach($_FILES as $key => $value){ 
     if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($key)){
      $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
      $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }else{   
        //This $data is the array I described before
      $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        //So if you this you will get the file name
      $filename = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
    }
  }
  $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: I am using upload class. i did'nt knEw that it will return a new changed file name after successfully uploading file. Can you tell me how to get the new changed file name. I want to save it to my db.

Comment: You have shown for single image upload. i have four image which users are uploading them atonce. How can i get the four name of image?

Comment: You have 4 input of type file or you only have one input and want to multiselect the files?

Comment: users is uploading four image from diffrent select  file option from same option

Comment: I've updated my code again, I'm not sure if it will work out of box, but main core is there

Comment: +1 for your help. i completed it by extending a method from upload class which gives me new updated name to save in my db.

Comment: No problem glad I could help you out. If you think that your problem is solved accept the answer